# jquery mobile changePage error

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Every time I click the link, I only get "error loading page".

```
<script>
    $('.popup').click(function(){
       $.mobile.changePage('http://www.google.com', 'slideup'); 
    });
</script>



<a class="popup" href="#">My Popup</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure changePage() method is only for linking between internal jQuery mobile "Pages"

You will most likely be getting an error because jQuery will be looking for a that URL in relation to your own website.

If you want to create an external link to Google, use the following in your anchor tag:

```
<a class="popup" href="http://www.google.com" rel="external" target="_blank">My Popup</a>
```

Because it's an external page, you can't use page transitions such as slideup etc

More reading here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if you can do it this way or it might be a cross domain issue.